# Can I get a Vaadin notification to appear wherever I want?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I was just reading about Notifications in the book of vaadin but I couldn't find the answer to this as it appears that all the notifications appear in the middle of the page. Basically I have a js generated popup that covers the left half of the page and I'd like to get a notification to appear inside that popup. Is it doable with vaadin notifications?
thanks

Comment: Take a look at [Valo theme demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!common). It is a show case for Vaadin components with the Valo theme applied. There is also a section for notifications where you can try out things. The source code is available, too.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

[Vaadin Notification Customization](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/application/application-notifications.html#application.notifications.customization) on the Online Docs.

The enum **Position** lets you specify in which position the notification should appear. You can't specify absolute position. Thought it could be done by CSS.

However you can't attach a Notification in a layout. At least not the Vaadin Core Notification. If you need to include it in a custom layout, you could create your own notification layout that is pretty easy.

Comment: thanks, the link is actually quite interesting. Problem is that even if I set the  right position with CSS the error message won't be bound to the js popup, so I think I'd have to create my own notification layout. You're saying it's rather easy, can you recommend any resource anywhere were I can find more specific info on that? thanks

Comment: Speaking in Vaadin Terms: A Notification Layout is basically a Window with a Vertical Layout with a Label inside (with the notification text). For a deeper example, you can try to take a look at [Vaadin Valo Theme Demo](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!common) **Common UI Elements** -> **Dialogs** That is basically how a "Home-Made" notification could be realized with Vaadin. You can also take a look at the source code at [Valo Demo Source](https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/tests/themes/valo) Regards

Comment: thanks. Just so I understand - as I'm new to vaadin - I checked those links and yes as you said they are all windows on their own, so, I'm thinking, if I want to have a notifcation, or error, inside a popup - in my case - which means it needs to be the same width as the popup of course, do you think that it might be a better idea to scrap the vaadin notification altogether and use some js errors instead, meaning, creating some divs with an error message in it, so that I can have full control and position them exactly where I want them?

Comment: In my opinion, this completely depends on your UI requirements. If do not feel comfortable with the "Vaadin way", go with the JS, otherwise stick with vaadin. If you don't like the idea to have another window popping up, then you could also add Label on top of your layout (meaning as very first component) and add some of the predefined Valo Styles for labels as shown [here](https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!labels). I would personally stick with Vaadin where possible.

Comment: OK thanks for your help I will play around with that and if I get stuck I'll post again